# Java Iterator Impose Condition on Next()

Tags: java, iterator

I'm a little confused about iterators in Java. How do I make next() only return certain values? Like say I have a boolean array of 10 elements, and I only want to return those that are true. Do I put a conditional in the next() method that checks for that condition and returns when it is met? Or do I check for the condition when I actually use the iterator and keep calling next() until I get a suitable value, and then use that value?

Similarly if I have an array of ints, and I want to create a string representation of the array where each element is separated by a space, but I only want to use negative elements. If I want to do this with an iterator, do I check for the negative element in the next() method and only return next values that are negative, or do I check when I'm making the string representation, and keep calling next() until I get a negative value, and then add that value to the string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, both are doable, so that's actually a design question. If you are sure every time you will iterate on that Iterable structure you will need that condition, than go with a condition in the next() method of a subclass of Iterator, but else, you better check in your app outside the Iterator.

Also, the test in the next() method could possibly improve performance, because you will iterate on a fewer number of elements in your applicative code. So if performance is an issue, maybe it's a good idea.

Answer (score 12):

[Normal Java iterators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) just iterate over every element of the collection. So you have to check the values yourself on each iteration.

What you wrote, can be done using the [`FilterIterator`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/FilterIterator.html) class from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).

From the JavaDoc:

> This iterator decorates the underlying iterator, only allowing through those elements that match the specified [`Predicate`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/FilterIterator.html).

Here's an example to get you started:

```
// Create a predicate class, like this:
class MyAwesomePredicate implements Predicate {

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(Object object) {

        // If the condition is satisfied, return true.
        // Return false otherwise.

    }     
}

// and pass it to the FilterIterator:
Iterator<SomeClass> matchingObjects = 
    new FilterIterator(myCollection.iterator(), new MyAwesomePredicate());

// Now iterate the maching objects:
while (machingObjects.hasNext() {

    // do your stuff

}
```

**Update:** If you prefer, there's also the [`Iterators#filter(Iterator<T>, Predicate<? super T>)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#filter%28java.util.Iterator,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries). Unlike Apache Commons, it has support for generics, and (arguably) higher *coolness factor*.

Comment: That seems an interesting solution.

Comment: +1 from me - I have learnt something today and it's not even 9am yet

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator` are used to iterate over a collection and will return every element one by one. There's no other way to use `Iterator`, so do your check in the iteration or create your own special iterator.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of iterator is dead simple: It hides (encapsulates) the implementation of traversal algorithm on you collection of elements.
You call next - it gets the next element on the collection, its up to you to decide what to with this value. By using an iterator you don't rely on the internal implementation of your collection.
Of course you can create your own iterator (it should implement java.util.Iterator interface) but I believe for what you ask its not required :)
Hope this helps